# call selection jquery event inside tinymce text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have been trying to call jQuery select function inside a tinymce text area after the text selection ends.

```
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

i tried to call the event in such way

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 300,
        menubar: false           




$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textArea').select(function(){
     var selectedText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
     console.log(selectedText);
  });
});
```

How can i call the event after the selection ends inside a tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

You should check tinymce events.
I think the one you need is this: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#nodechange

```
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',
 init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
 editor.on('NodeChange', function (e) {
    console.log('Node changed');
    });
  }
});
```