# How to listen for text selected in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to get the text selected event from tinymce, the way i do is as follows

```
const editor = global["tinymce"].activeEditor;
editor.on("NodeChange", e => {
  const selectedText = editor.selection.getContent({ format: "text" });

});
```

Tinymce is already loaded by **wordpress** before including this code, the problem i face is the NodeChange event is not triggered on the editor instance. I dont want to create a tinymce plugin for this, is this possible without creating a plugin?
 The code i have pasted here actually works if i add it via the console, i am missing something when i load it normally

Comment: yes it is possible and you're on the right track. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228768/call-selection-jquery-event-inside-tinymce-text-selection

Comment: @GrafiCode Thanks, but the usecase of mine is different than the link you have mentioned, in my case tinymce is initalized by wordpress, i cant reinitialize it again

Comment: I get it, in this case you should look for event binding after init:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514994/tinymce-how-bind-on-event-after-its-initialized

Comment: and i forget to add, the code i have pasted here actually works if i add it in the console, i am missing something when i load it normally.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a timing issue.  The editor is not "active" until TinyMCE has fully initialized.  If you try to call:

```
const editor = global["tinymce"].activeEditor;
```

...before the editor is fully initialized the `editor` variable is likely `null`.

WordPress has a variety of hooks to allow you to tweak the TinyMCE configuration and that is likely a more reliable way to do what you are trying to do. You can absolutely use the setup function in the TinyMCE configuration to add your NodeChange code.

Packaging that into a WordPress plugin would certainly make it easier to deploy/update your solution but its not a requirement.

Comment: sadly, the editor variable isnt null, i did a log on that editor, it just doesn't get the events.

Comment: And actually i can package my code inside a wordpress plugin, i dont want to create tinymce plugin for that.